# ActiveRecord::No Database Error Fatal: Role "..."does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I'm working a project collaboratively with others. It is deployed to heroku and it we're using postgresql.

I want to make changes in a local branch and see my changes in the web browser right away.

How can I do this with heroku?

I'm working in Cloud9 development environment and I used to enter "rails s -p $PORT -b $IP" to view my changes in the app, but now when I do that, I get a "no database error."

I've tried googling things but I'm still confused. How can I make changes to an exisiting app and see my changes locally (without pushing to origin/master)? I've never worked with databases before... using the pre-programmed cloud9, things were just working. I'm not sure how to create a separate database for heroku if that's what is needed.

Here is a copy of my database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
# default: &default
#   adapter: sqlite3
#   pool: 5
#   timeout: 5000

# development:
#   <<: *default
#   database: db/development.sqlite3

# # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
# test:
#   <<: *default
#   database: db/test.sqlite3

# production:
#   <<: *default
#   database: db/production.sqlite3

# FOR HEROKU -- POSTGRES DB SETUP
# UNCOMMENT WHEN WORKING LOCALLY.
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: planit_developement
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: planit_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000


# production:
#   <<: *default
#   database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Here is the full trace when I try to migrate:

```
rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:665:in `rescue in connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:913:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: Sounds like you're using a different environment to what is actually there. eg your db is usually production environment (or maybe staging) if it's already up on heroku. what is your db called? is it the same as what you have in `config/database.yml` ?

Comment: are you on a different system? do you actually have a database set up on it? or do you need to import a copy of your db from heroku to your local environment?

Comment: Can you show the content of your `database.yml`?

Comment: I haven't worked with databases before so I could be asking a dumb question... I edited the above post to include my database.yml.